# Filter shopify products using shopify-connector

Tags: shopify

I am trying to get and sync Shopify products to my own database and after that, we will show those products in our mobile application what I want to do is I want to filter products that only enable to sp-tools-shopify-connector under sales channel and app section how can I filter this using Shopify API

[image]

Comment: You need to check sale channels rest API for it [link](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/sales-channels/productlisting) it will help you to list the products that are available for particular app

Comment: yes, we can do it when we sync all products, but after we sync all products we will get products details from our database not from the shopify, the only thing we do is when some one update the product through the shopify we will update that information in our database trough web hook but I can not find anything to capture is this is available or not for the app

Comment: You need to register the webhook and listen the same on added location and catch the response when webhook sends the data from Shopify over product creation and updation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Storefront API, you don't need to filter anything, as Shopify will only show products with your sales channel enabled in product settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can always filter or remove lines in the exported CSV before you import.